# Generic Function Macros and How to Suppress Specific GCC Warning: "Pointer Type Mismatch in Conditional Expression"

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, macros, c11

Before someone instantly marks this as a duplicate, let me say that I have spent a few hours searching for an answer to this (and read many similar S/O questions)

Here's the situation: I'm playing around with `_Generic` and trying to implement a dictionary structure which auto-casts upon retrieval. Let me explain (*if you don't care, skip ahead to the bold header*). From what I see, the go-to way to have a dictionary structure in which all values belong to the same field involves `void` pointers, which require the user to cast upon retrieval; here is an example:

```c
struct C99_Dict *d = new_C99_Dict(); /* Creates a pointer to an empty dict
                                        d: {} */
int i = 7;
put_in_c99_dict(d,"key",i); /* d: {"key": (void *)&i} */
...
// BAD: Will cast to i's address
int j = get_from_c99_dict(d,"key");
// BAD: Dereferencing void pointer
int k = *(get_from_c99_dict(d,"key"));
// GOOD: Will set l equal to 7
int l = *(int *)get_from_c99_dict(d,"key");
```

As one might imagine, after a while (especially once `struct *`s get thrown into the mix...although that's unchanged in my current project) your code ends up looking like something out of a Lisp textbook.

Using `_Generic`, however, I have managed to figure out a way to make an easier-to-use dictionary which auto-casts in such a fashion that the line

```c
int j = get_from_c11_dict(d,"key");
```

becomes perfectly valid and works as one would expect (for builtins...structs still require manual casting). Changing the behavior of `put_in_c11_dict` based on the input type is easy enough, for the `_Generic` keyword does all of the heavy lifting. What is difficuly, however, is the notion of casting on the way *out*. This is because, in order for the dictionary `struct` to be well-defined, its value must be a consistent type (e.g. `void*`, as I have implemented). The problem with this, however, is that the type information is lost after the insertion function has processed the given input.

My initial (failed) attempt at a workaround for this was to make a dictionary struct of the following form:

```c
typedef struct _dict_mem_struct{
  union {
    _Bool(*bool_get)(_dict_mem_struct*);
    char(*char_get)(_dict_mem_struct*);
    ...
    char *(*char_point_get)(_dict_mem_struct*);
    void *(*void_point_get)(_dict_mem_struct*);
  } get;
  void *value;
} _dict_mem_t;
```

In hopes of (albeit perhaps foolishly so) being able to do the following in a `_get` helper macro definition:

```c
#define _get(mem_struct) _Generic((mem_struct.get) ... )
```

Unfortunately, I then learned from gdb that `mem_struct.get` was of type `union`, so it was back to the drawing board. Eventually, I got something that worked. First, I added a `char*` field to the member structure which contained the original type. Then what I really needed was an inlined switch statement, since I had no prior indication of what the function signature would be. So, here's the hideous thing I did (is it technically invalid C? Maybe. Probably. I don't know. Nevertheless, GCC compiles it and it works, so I'm happy.)

```c
#define IS_PFX(val,pfx) (!strcmp(val->pfx, pfx))
#define _get(valstruct) (IS_PFX(valstruct,"bool") ? boolval(valstruct) : IS_PFX(valstruct,"char") ? charval(valstruct) : ... : valstruct)
```

Yeah, I know; I'm probably going to hell for this. So, with that...

**Here's my actual problem:** When I compile this, it works, but gcc gets extremely upset with me. It gives me a bunch of errors such as

```
dict.c:203:75: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression
 #define PAIR(valstruct,str,fn,rst) (IS_PFX(valstruct,str) ? fn(valstruct) : rst)
```

From what I can gather, this means gcc is upset that these functions are all of different types. Nevertheless, as previously stated, the code *works*, so I would like to tell gcc to put a sock in it for specifically those warnings. The problem is that when I run `gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option`, those warning lines have no `-W...` flag after them. Furthermore, I have read through the gcc warning flag page, and nothing stands out as obvious to me which I could use to suppress these. Finally, the warnings still do not go away after adding the lines `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"` and `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wextra"`. How can I get rid of these? Another solution I would be fine with is somehow turning off all warnings for specifically that file, since the reason I don't want them is so that I can integrate this into other projects without headache.

Thanks for any and all assistance. By the way, if there is some better way to do all of this, then *please* let me know. Regardless, I'm thinking I'll make a git repo for this once I've worked some of these kinks out, since I think it would be useful (if so, I'll update this post with a link).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc is probably right, you are mixing different pointer types in a ternary expression. So your design is most probably wrong. Have in mind that `_Generic` can't do miracles, the type system in C remains static, determined at compile time. It can only take care of type information that you pass to it in the first expression.

If you cast away type information to `void*`, store the pointer somewhere and try to retrieve it later, by definition `_Generic` can't help you. The context of the retrieval doesn't have the type information anymore, it might be called for such pointers that come from different places.

So in particular for a dictionary structure C can never know at the retrieval side, what type the original pointer had been. If you want to keep that information, you'd have to do that yourself and store that information along with the pointer.

BTW, already your question title is wrong: there is no such thing as a generic function in C. There are type generic function-like macros.

Comment: Updated the title

I am aware that the type information is gone, and I cannot think of a way to prevent that. You say "if you want to keep that information, you'd have to do that yourself and store that information along with the pointer;" is there some way I can do that *other* than what I am currently doing? I know that C does not have a `type` type, and I need to have some sort of consistent encoding for the type representation in order to have a well-defined dictionary type. Is there some better type encoding?

Comment: @belph, you could e.g keep a pointer to a function that processes your data along with the data. But then this depends a lot of what you want to do with it, I don't think that there is a general recipe.